# Get the mean of df values that the index is equal to n

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this:

```
           0
0   0.395554
1   0.191111
2   0.126189
3   0.116665
4   0.056115
..       ...
15  0.063980
16  0.066663
17  0.069018
18  0.066210
19  0.064462

[740 rows x 1 columns]
```

Every 20 values the index numeration is repeated. 0 to 19 is repeated 37 times in index.

I want to calculate the mean of all values that have 0 in index values, 1 in index values, ..... 19 in index values.

I tried this but it's not efficient:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=False)
dfave0=df.loc[df['index']==0].mean()
dfave1=df.loc[df['index']==1].mean()
....
....
dfave19=df.loc[df['index']==19].mean()
```

I'm beginner in python. Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `level` parameter in `groupby` to aggregate by index (since there's only one level of index, you can use `level=0`):

```
df.groupby(level=0).mean()

           0
0  -0.163535
1  -0.023870
2   0.148520
3  -0.078853
4  -0.026177
5   0.019133
6  -0.158570
7  -0.177121
8   0.032237
9  -0.392289
10  0.323945
11  0.134139
12  0.033717
13 -0.295030
14 -0.085907
15 -0.228847
16  0.022979
17 -0.095209
18 -0.352146
19 -0.270108
```